# laravel upload image in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, file-upload, laravel-4

I am trying to upload images in laravel 4. Locally it works, upload image and save the path in database, but the problem is that when deploy with google app engine it doesn't works. It shows this error:

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException Call to
>   a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on a non-object

view

```
{{ Form::model($v, array('files' => true,'route' => array('upload.image', $v->id),'method' => 'post','class'=>'form-horizontal','id'=>'upload-images')) }}
            {{ Form::file('image') }}
            <br>
            {{ Form::submit('Add Photo', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary' )) }}
            {{ Form::close() }}
```

controller

```
$file = Input::file('image');

        $destinationPath = 'img_gallery/';
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename = 'img_' . $id . '.' . $extension;
        $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);

        $car = Car::find($id);
        $car->Pic = $filename;
        $car->save();
```

if i try dd($file) it shows NULL.
What's the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

gae doesn't let you to upload directy files but use must read this first https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/user_upload#createuploadurl_options